# Xamarin Forms get values of SelectedItemChangedEventArgs

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, selecteditem

I'm currently working on the Xamarin Forms to develop an iOS app.

I got stuck on getting values of selecteditem on listview.

my code is :

```
listview.ItemSelected += (sender ,e) => {
SelectedItemChangedEventArgs b= e
object abc= b.SelectedItem
var topage = new topage();
};
```

However the value of abc is Todo.Datasource and inside there I have "Icon name" and "Name". I want to get those two names, however, there is no way to get it.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you,

Comment: Try var item=abs as classname means object convert into icon name class name

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your ItemsSource is a `List<Widget>`, you would do

```
listview.ItemSelected += (sender ,e) => {
  Widget item = (Widget) listview.SelectedItem;
  // reference whatever properties of Widget you need here
};
```